# Issues inserting special characters in Postgresql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sql-insert, psycopg2

I've test table containing the following columns: id:int, status:string and payload:jsonb

I have in a tuple the values to insert in the test table:

```
record=(1234567, 'ERROR','{"header": "Response", "status": "Err", "Details": "Replace ''Jonh''s Assoc.'' → ''Jonh''s Civil Assoc."}')
```

Passing the record to the cursor for execution:

```
cur.execute('insert into test VALUES {};'.format(record))
```

The insert statement looks as this after executing the query:

```
insert into test VALUES (1234567, 'ERROR','{"header": "Response", "status": "Err", "Details": "Replace \'\'John\'\'s Assoc.\'\' → \'\'John\'\'s Civil Assoc."}');
```

If you noticed, the string is adding back slash to every quote. So I ended up with the following error:

```
(psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "\"
"Details": "Example: Replace \'\'John\'\'s...
                                                             ^
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `... "issues": [{"issue": "one": [{"Details": ...`: this is not valid JSON to start with.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, a single quote is escaped by another single quote, not a backslash. I would recommend using legitimate [query parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) rather than the python string formatting method, so the database driver can properly handle the escaping for you.

```
cur.execute('insert into test(id, status, payload) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', record);
```

You can even individually force the conversion of a parameter if you like to (although it should not be necessary here):

```
cur.execute('insert into test(id, status, payload) VALUES (?, ?, ?::jsonb)', record);
```

Comment: Getting the following error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys'. I've searched, but I have no clue about this error.

Answer (score 0):

When formatting a simple string such as `Test String` is correct to add `\'` to have `\'Test String\'`. However, when passing JSON as string, the string has more than one level, so adding `\'` would affect the expected syntaxis.

Because invoking format function in a given string is providing a correct format just at a first level, the strings which are more complex are affected and received the `\'`. So, I ended up removing `\'` from the string to make it work.

I did not like the workaround, but I would apply it until getting a better fix:

```
 cur.execute('insert into test VALUES {};'.format(record).replace("\\", "")
```

Thanks